# Hive ODBC driver does not recognise unix_timestamp

Tags: sql, hive, odbc

**Short version:**

How can I get the difference in seconds between 2 timestamps, via the ODBC driver?

**Long version:**

Using ODBC for a simple query (not that I use cast (... as timestamp) to have a standalone line, the actual query runs against a table with timestamp data):

```
select unix_timestamp(cast('2019-02-01 01:02:03' as timestamp)) as tto
```

I got the error message:

> unix_timestamp is not a valid scalar function or procedure call

I could not find any configuration option that would change this. Native query is disabled (because I am using prepared statements) and other functions work fine. My guess is that unix_timestamp() (without parameter) is deprecated, and the driver is a bit enthusiastic about preventing using the function.

I tried to work around the problem, and I cast the timestamp as bigint instead of using the unix_timestamp function:

```
select cast(cast('2019-02-01 01:02:03' as timestamp) as bigint)
```

This works fine! But when I try to get the diff of 2 timestamps:

```
select cast(cast('2019-02-01 01:02:03' as timestamp) as bigint) - cast(cast('2019-02-01 01:02:03' as timestamp) as bigint)
```

I got the message

> Operand types SQL_WCHAR and SQL_WCHAR are incompatible for the binary
>   minus operator

(but then only for complex queries, not if the query consists only of this select).

The driver will accept a diff between 2 timestamps, but then I end up with an interval type, which I cannot convert back to seconds.

I would consider that those are bugs in the ODBC driver, but I cannot contact Hortonworks because I am not a paying customer, and I cannot contact Simba either because I am not a paying customer.

On a side note, if I try to use the `floor` function, I get the message:

> ‘floor’ is a reserved keyword.

Yes, I know it's reserved and I am actually trying to ise it.

Any idea how I could get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the official Hive ODBC driver is really *really* **really** bad if you cannot use native statements (ie. if you need parameterised queries).

My suggested workarounds are to either get a paying one (eg. https://www.progress.com/datadirect-connectors - I tried it and it works very well) or to just use a jdbc one if your application can support it. All ODBC drivers I found for Hive are wrappers around the jdbc one anyway, bundling a jre.